# Diferença de minutos entre duas datas python

Tags: python, data, time

Estou trabalhando com dados de um restaurante. Gostaria de calcular o tempo de permanência do restaurante em minutos. Tenho duas variáveis t1-entrada do pedido e t2-fechamento do pedido. Estou tendo problemas para calcular os minutos.

Uma pessoa que entrou no restaurante 23:00:00 no dia 03/08/2022 e saiu 01:30:00 do dia 04/08/2022. Quando faço a diferença dá 1 dia, 22 horas, 30 minutos. Estou usando o pacote `datetime`.

Criei variáveis Horas finais e iniciais e datas finais e iniciais e fiz a operação abaixo:

```
permanencia = (Hora_final + Data_final) - (Hora_inicial + Hora_final)
print(permanencia)
```

Erro:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.date'
> ```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)

Comment: Como vc cria as variáveis `Hora_final`, `Data_final`, `Hora_inicial` e `Hora_final`? Pela mensagem de erro, parece que elas são de tipos incompatíveis (uma é `date`, outra é  `time`), por isso não dá para somá-las. Se for esse o caso, uma solução melhor seria criar um `datetime', e aí vc obtém a diferença: https://ideone.com/qm7Ecf

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, voce quer subtrair duas datas e obter o tempo entre elas, a questão é que pelo erro que vc colocou, vc está tentando somar tipos de datas incompatíveis e pra resolver isso basta criar as datas completas assim:

```py
import datetime

# ano, mes, dia, hora, minuto, segundo
dt_final = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 4, 1, 30, 0)
dt_inicial = datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 3, 23, 0, 0)

diferenca = dt_final - dt_inicial
print(diferenca)
```

o resultado é:

```
2:30:00
```

Para mais informações sobre isso, recomendo dar uma pesquisada na biblioteca `datetime`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, não sabia dessas convenções, vou dar uma lida.